# how to make angular app using spring boot backend receive only requests from local area network?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I'm developing an angular app with jwt authentication and a spring boot backend.
For the moment, i would like my app to be available only for all PC connected to the local-area-network.

For angular, i tried ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 and my app was available for all pc's on the network at the ip of the pc serving the app followed be :4200.

The spring boot is also running on the same PC.

But, when i try to login from a different PC in the local area network, my credentials don't work, i get connection refused in the chrome console.

In intellij, i get no message, a sign that no request arrives to spring.

On the PC that is running angular and spring boot i can successfully authenticate with the same credentials, i get no errors.

This is my WebSecurity in spring boot:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/socket").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I left the routes to auth(my authentication) and socket to be permitted to all.
When i try in a browser, the ip of the pc running the angular app and spring boot server followed by :8080, my exception handling is taking care of it and displays in intellij "Unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource".

This means a request acceses the spring boot server but, of course, without credentials, the request is shut down.

As a difference, when trying pc_ip:4200, my angular app is rendered, i try authentication, "connection refused" in chrome console, when trying pc_ip:8080, i get the request in spring but my exception handler handles it.

I'm thinking, i have to to extra configuration in spring ? What am i missing ?

Kind regards,

EDIT 1:  this is the error i get in chrome console when i try to login.

EDIT 2 : It looks like my angular app is trying to login using http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login instead of pc_ip:8080/api/auth/login because that is where the server lives, not localhost:8080. Any ideas to tell the cliend to forward the requests it to the correct route ?

EDIT3: I edited in spring security to let permitall to all application. On the other PC, i now can browse through my application typing pc_ip:8080/ and adding any of my urls defined in controllers. Also, on pc_ip:4200 my angular app lives. How can i remake my setup so that only one ip on a different pc runs my application?

EDIT4: Thanks to georgeB i managed to solve almost all of my problems, but the websocket is still not working on the other PC in the network. I attached a printscreen to show the error. I don't understand, why on the PC that runs angular and spring there is no problem with webbsocket, and on another PC all authentications, requests are ok, but the websocket is not ok.

EDIT5: For stomp implementation i use https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/ng2-stompjs/2018/11/04/ng2-stomp-with-angular7.html

The implementantion is simple:

```
export const myRxStompConfig: InjectableRxStompConfig = {
 brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/api/socket',
heartbeatIncoming: 0, 
heartbeatOutgoing: 20000, 
reconnectDelay: 200,
};
```

Then in the final i add

```
const config: InjectableRxStompConfig = { ...myRxStompConfig, 
connectHeaders: headers};
   this.rxStompService.configure(config);
  this.rxStompService.activate();
  this.rxStompService.watch('/topic/server-broadcaster')
 .subscribe((message: Message) => {
 });
```

[image]

[image: this is the error i get in chrome console when i try to login.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the instructions and create a proxy to the backend.
I think it solves your problems but i don't know how it will handle the websocket communications.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

I think you need a more elaborate answer from someone who uses extensively websocket with spring and angular.

Comment: You are right. your answer solved my problems except the websocket. I attached a prinscreen at EDIT4: to explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the proxy config file to point to the right ip address instead of localhost, so:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://pc_ip:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I can't say I know what is going on with the WebSocket Error wthout looking at your STOMP over WebSocket implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I added an edit 5 with clarifications for websocket.

Comment: for websocket i tried , "/ws": {
        "target": "ws://192.168.0.106:8080/api",
        "secure": false
    } and in brokerURL: 'ws/socket', i get something like failed to construct Websocket, the  /api/socket is invalid